# C help: Using clock_gettime more than one seemingly keeps returning 0.000001

Tags: c, timer

I'm trying to code a part of a program that uses **clock_gettime** to record the runtime of two different calculating functions. One of them prints the calculation time for each iteration of a number with no issue - the time increases the higher the input value, n, becomes.

However, for a second function, **it keeps printing 0.000001 on the way down.** I've checked my code repeatedly; and i'm not sure why it keeps printing this way. My code could be okay, and the output is to be expected, but I am not too confident on that possibility.

I will disclose that this is for an assignment i'm doing for a class, and a significant portion is already complete. This is the only part that i'm just stuck on and I want to figure out what it is i'm missing to result in this value constantly being printed.

**Edit: Someone pointed out that it was printing in microseconds and not nanoseconds - so I had to increase the amount of decimal places that could be printed. That started giving me the proper output.**

```
    for(i = 0;i <= n; i++)
    {
        //func_a
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
        func_a(i);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

        nr_runtime = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)
                + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000000000.0;

        //----------------------------------------------

        //func_b
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
        func_b(i);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

        nr_runtime = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)
                + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000000000.0;
     }
```

The functions:

```
int func_a(int n) //recursive fibonacci
{
    int i; 
    
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return n; 
    }
    else
    {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    }
}

int func_b(int n) //Iterative fibonacci
{

    int a=0, b=1, c;

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return n; 
    }

    else
    {
        int i;

        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            c = a + b; //next term
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Output for func_a:

```
actual numbers like 0.00234 to 1.73564
```

Output for func_b:

```
0.000001 going onward until value of n is reached
```

I checked my functions and both of them output the same calculated values using different methods of calculation - so I know that part is fine...which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: what does the second function do? If you put the function to your answer I can try it on my computer and we ll see then.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli Both of the functions are for calculating numbers in a Fibonacci sequence both recursively and iteratively. Function a is for recursively calculating, and function b is for iteratively calculating.

Comment: Maybe the compiler optimizes b to a closed form computation of Fibonacci numbers. You need to include the definitions of a and b functions, and also the version of compiler you are using.

Comment: @tal_code yes please include the functions and we can test.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli I updated with the functions

Comment: @tal_code Better to post the code that performs the output.   `func_a()` has not output.  "it keeps printing 0.000001 on the way down." is not supported by the posted code. 
 See [mcve]

Comment: @tal_code The code is fine, If you entirely remove the part where func_a's time and calculated and enter like an absurd number like 1000000 to ```n``` then you can see that the time increases. It is just that the function is really really fast. I got the running time to be ```0.000352``` for ```n = 130000```

Comment: How big is _n_? Let's assume it was 60. `func_a` will need a quadrillion calculations to calculate that. Whereas `func_b` needs 60. What's the surprise? __Yes__, your second algorithm really _is_ that much faster.

Comment: The iterative one will be a lot faster.  Try testing a much larger n.  You will overflow a 32-bit int quite quickly.  Even a 64-bit long will overflow at n=92.   The `timespec` returned has times in nanoseconds, yet your example is only shown to microseconds.  Try printing the time out to the nanosecond and see if it changes.

Comment: @TrentP ahh i didn't know i had it in micro - i thought dividing by 1000000000 was the conversion i needed. Thank you

Comment: Dividing by 1,000,000,000 is correct, but you said the time printed is `0.000001`.  There should be three more digits after the decimal place to display nanoseconds.

Comment: @TrentP ahh i see now

Comment: @TrentP so what i ended up doing was specifying how many decimal places are printed. Instead of using %f, i used %.10f and that seemed to have worked. It is showing much more than just 0.000001

Comment: You could make the first function use memoization so that it doesn't need to recalculate results and then it would be as fast as the second version.